# setInterval doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery, timer, setinterval

I have a timer, but I can't stop it.

This is my HTML code

```
<div id="timer">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="hour">00</div>
        <div class="divider">:</div>
        <div id="minute">00</div>
        <div class="divider">:</div>
        <div id="second">00</div>
        <button id="btn-start" disabled="true">Comenzar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have this function.

```
function tiempoOn(){
    var time = {
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
        second: 0
    };
    var time_runing = null;
        if ( $("#btn-start").text() == 'Start' )
        {
            $("#btn-start").text('Stop');                       
            time_runing = setInterval(function(){
                time.second++;
                if(time.second >= 60)
                {
                    time.second = 0;
                    time.minute++;
                }      
                if(time.minute >= 60)
                {
                    time.minute = 0;
                    time.hour++;
                }
                $("#hour").text(time.hour < 10 ? '0' + time.hour : time.hour);
                $("#minute").text(time.minute < 10 ? '0' + time.minute : time.minute);
                $("#second").text(time.second < 10 ? '0' + time.second : time.second);
            }, 1000);
        }else if ( $("#btn-start").text() == 'Stop' )
        {
            $("#btn-start").text('Start');
            clearInterval(time_runing);
            $("#hour").text("00");
            $("#minute").text("00");
            $("#second").text("00");   
        }
    }
```

In my `document.ready` function have

```
if($("#second").html()=="00"){
    tiempoOn();
    $("#hour").text("GO");
    $("#minute").text("GO");
    $("#second").text("GO");
}else{

}
```

At the start, my bottom has this text: "Start"

When I press a key, my timer starts.

Bottom now has text: "stop" and my function starts.
But when I call again to my function, enter on second part:

```
$("#btn-start").text('Start');
clearInterval(time_runing);
$("#hour").text("00");
$("#minute").text("00");
$("#second").text("00");
```

But my timer continues. Have temporally (1 second) 00:00:00 but it continues on to 00:00:23, for example.

Any ideas?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English

Comment: "At the start, my bottom" - not making fun of your English (it's perfectly good enough!) but this bit just made me chuckle. The word you were after is "button". A bottom is er.... something completely different.

Comment: @Jamiec keep in mind that the text is corrected by Druzion

Answer (score -2):

Everything is perfect but value of text button is "Comenzar"

While you add a check for value "start" of same button.

Just change the value of that button and your code will work fine. You can check the working code on following link

[Fiddly](http://fiddly.org/d1dca)